# Maven, javadoc : No source files for package

Tags: java, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm writing a maven [package](https://github.com/LaurentClaessens/frtex) with directory structure

```
frtex
   pom.xml
frtex/src/main/java/some-files.java
frtex/src/main/java/utils/some-other-files.java
```

Making `mvn test` works fine.

My problem is `mvn javadoc:javadoc` that produces the right documentation for the files contained in `frtex/src/main/java` but issuing

```
[WARNING] javadoc: warning - No source files for package utils
```

Here is the relevant(?) part of my pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <groups>
            <group>
                <title>TI</title>
                <packages>frtex.*</packages>
            </group>
        </groups>

        <doclet>ch.raffael.doclets.pegdown.PegdownDoclet</doclet>
        <docletArtifact>
            <groupId>ch.raffael.pegdown-doclet</groupId>
            <artifactId>pegdown-doclet</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </docletArtifact>
        <useStandardDocletOptions>true</useStandardDocletOptions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

in `project/build/plugins`

What should I do to make maven/javadoc found the files in `src/main/java/utils` ?

Answer (score 12):

This is a late response, but I just ran into the same issue.

The solution is you need to add the following to your plugin inside the `configuration` section

```
<configuration>
   <sourcepath>src/main/java</sourcepath>
   ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Would be interesting to know why this should work, because it's the default path.

Comment: strangely, this does help. I'm inheriting this from parent pom so maybe the default is not set in some cases

Comment: This is helpful, but I think it solves a newer problem than the OP’s. The maven-javadoc-plugin uses a different default sourcepath, ${project.build.directory}/apidocs/src during the deploy phase, unless you configure it in your pom.xml as ${project.build.sourceDirectory}.

Comment: Not the OPs problem but it solved mine, and I found OP's post using the error message, so it's useful info!

Comment: I tried this, but I still get this problem...

Comment: Glad I found this answer :)

Answer (score 6):

Although [locus2k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54467008/9658836) worked for me in the beginning, it was only covering up the real underlying issue I had with Javadoc not being able to find the directory structure.

In my case, I created in IntelliJ -by mistake- a single dir structure with dots  separating them, like: `src/main/java/wrong.folder.structure/` instead of:
`src/main/java/right/folder/structure/`

The collapsed view in IntelliJ was showing both structures as the same.

Maybe not everyone's issue, but it was mine.

Comment: Bingo! That was it!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not in your maven configuration.

You need to include a `package-info.java` for the utils package.

It is a file located at `src/main/java/utils/package-info.java` that will contain the javadoc for the package, in contrast to the javadoc for a class.

For more information about package-level javadocs, [you can read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#packagecomment).

Comment: How do I invoke maven after that ? Just adding the proposed file and invoking `mvn javadoc:javadoc` results in the same warning.

Comment: I don't know your entire setup, but generally you need to run your maven build to get a new build.  It might be possible to run a specific target (like you did) to get the desired item, but knowing the exact way to run that specific target is unique to each maven build configuration.  If it were me, I'd just run a new full build.

Comment: Why getting `javadoc: warning - No source files for package utils` , is it because missing `package-info.java` ?

Comment: @prime Probably.

Comment: Something I noticed was that the package-info.java file is not compiled unless you specify annotation with Retention=RUNTIME or pass `-Xpkginfo:always` to javac.  The package-info.java kind of solves this problem but introduces one of the aforementioned workarounds.  I am not convinced that this is a better option than the sourcepath configuration, but it's definitely a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can also occur, if you use a newer Java version to build the project, though the warning is an error then, which makes the build fail. In my case, I was building a Java 8 project with a Java 12 (Bellsoft) JDK.

To solve this, you could either use a Java 8 JDK or, perhaps better, add `<source>8</source>` to the `configuration` section of the `maven-javadoc-plugin` (similar to @locus2k [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54467008/4423698)).