# Java 11/12 Javadoc with maven results in not generating Javadocs for tests

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, java-11, java-12

I have a small project with the following structure:

```
pom.xml

src/main/java/
  module-info.java
  de.ps.pl.te/
    package-info.java
    TE.java

src/test/java/
   de.ps.pl.te.test/
     package-info.java
     TETests.java
```

Also within my maven pom I defined the javadoc plugin as follows:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <show>protected</show>
          <failOnError>false</failOnError>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Now I got some strange outputs during running

```
mvn clean install site
```

> [INFO] Generating "Javadoc" report       --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.0:aggregate-no-fork
> [ERROR] Error fetching link: D:\work\eclipse\java\FritzBox\phplib\target\javadoc-bundle-options. Ignored it.
>
> [...]
>
> [INFO] Generating "Test Javadoc" report  --- maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.0:test-aggregate-no-fork
>
> [ERROR] Error fetching link: D:\work\eclipse\java\FritzBox\phplib\target\javadoc-bundle-options. Ignored it.
>
> Loading source files for package de.ps.pl.te.test...
>
> 1 error
>
> [ERROR] Error while creating javadoc report:
>
> Exit code: 2 - javadoc: error - No source files for package de.powerstat.phplib.templateengine.test
>
> Command line was: [...]javadoc.exe @options @packages
>
> Refer to the generated Javadoc files in '[...]' dir.
>
> org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException:
>
> Exit code: 2 - javadoc: error - No source files for package de.ps.pl.te.test
>
> Command line was: [...]javadoc.exe @options @packages
>
> Refer to the generated Javadoc files in '[...]\target\site\testapidocs' dir.
>
> at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeJavadocCommandLine (AbstractJavadocMojo.java:5761)
>
> at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeReport (AbstractJavadocMojo.java:2148)
>
> at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.TestJavadocReport.executeReport (TestJavadocReport.java:162)
>
> [...]

I studied the following question:

- [Maven, javadoc : No source files for package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958104/maven-javadoc-no-source-files-for-package)

But my problem seems to be different and based on java modularisation.
So the question is how to fix it - or is it more to make a bug report?

**EDIT 1**

Now I tried with JDK 11.0.3 and JDK 12.0.1 - I was unable to download OpenJDK because of oracle certificate and server problems - so I could not test OpenJDK 13 early access.

The interesting point is that the error message differs slighly when using version 11/12.

With JDK 11 the error is:

> Exit code: 1 - Project\src\main\java\module-info.java:12: error: module not found: org.apache.logging.log4j
> requires org.apache.logging.log4j;

With JDK 12 the error is:

> Exit code: 1 - error: module not found: de.powerstat.phplib.templateengine

The rest of the message is still the same.

Also I found a bug report that might be involved here:

[Javadoc does not support module-info in a multi-release jar](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8208269)

Also I tried to exclude the module-info.java without success:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <show>protected</show>
    <failOnError>false</failOnError>
    <sourceFileExcludes>
      <sourceFileExclude>**/module-info.java</sourceFileExclude>
    </sourceFileExcludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**EDIT 2**

Within target\site\apidocs I could finde the following (maven generated?) files:

- argfile
- javadoc.bat
- options
- packages

argfile:

```
'D:/TemplateEngine/src/main/java/de/ps/pl/te/package-info.java'
'D:/TemplateEngine/src/main/java/de/ps/pl/te/TemplateEngine.java'
```

javadoc.bat:

```
D:\Programme\Java\jdk-11.0.3\bin\javadoc.exe @options @argfile
```

packages:

```
de.powerstat.phplib.templateengine
de.powerstat.phplib.templateengine
```

options:

```
--module-path
'C:/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.11.2/log4j-api-2.11.2.jar;C:/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.2/log4j-core-2.11.2.jar'
-sourcepath
'D:/TemplateEngine/src/main/java'
-d
'D:/TemplateEngine/target/site/apidocs'
-linkoffline
'https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api' 'D:/TemplateEngine/target/javadoc-bundle-options'
[Removed uninteresting parts like encoding, title etc.]
```

For the case that someone would like to try it him-/herself I have made the whole project now available at [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerStat/TemplateEngine)

**EDIT 3:**

Some of the above mentioned problems have been vanished with updating to Java 11.0.10 or other newer versions.
But still one problem is around - which I have reported as a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MJAVADOC/issues/MJAVADOC-673?filter=allopenissues).

Comment: So you didn't put TETests in the same package as TE? Any, both should work, but I guess all combinations with module descriptos aren't covered yet. I'd suggest to create an issue for it at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC together with this small project as zip.

Comment: Did you try with java 11 or java 13? I don't reproduce it with theses version. also maybe provide the full pom and the package-info. Also if you don't use module-info  your application is not modularized.

Comment: What Maven version are you using?

Comment: @ParanoidUser: Latest 3.6

Comment: @pdem: I will try some things in the next days and then I let you know

Comment: I updated with some more information under EDIT 1

Comment: It might be better to you provide a minimal example project on some public git repo

Comment: tried to reproduce the problem with following structure https://imgur.com/a/pTQ9SZI and was not able to reproduce it everything worked fine.

Comment: Do you have `<sourcepath>src/main/java</sourcepath>` defined in the `<configuration>` section of the pom file? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#sourcepath

Comment: No I don't have, because thats the default.

Comment: Are you getting the same error when you run `mvn javadoc:javadoc` post you exclude module-info file ?

Comment: @Sachin Sorry for the late response, but yes I got the same error when running just mvn javadoc:javadoc

Comment: @Marinos An I made my project now available on github - see EDIT 2

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into the same error. Looked like it was because of maven-shade-plugin in my repo. I was using an older version of 1.6 and upgraded it to 3.2.4 and this error was gone.

Comment: This should be a comment on the question, not an answer. Down voting.

Comment: Upvoting as it sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

While testing I seen this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site (default-site) on project templateengine: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site failed: could not find reports directory [C:\tmp\TemplateEngine\target\pit-reports]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please copy and paste the information and the complete stacktrace below when reporting an issue
[ERROR] VM : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
[ERROR] Vendor : Oracle Corporation
[ERROR] Version : 12.0.1+12
[ERROR] Uptime : 146619
[ERROR] Input ->
[ERROR]  1 : -Dclassworlds.conf=C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/maven/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin/m2.conf
[ERROR]  2 : -Dmaven.home=C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/maven/apache-maven-3.6.1
[ERROR]  3 : -Dlibrary.jansi.path=C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/maven/apache-maven-3.6.1/lib/jansi-native
[ERROR]  4 : -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:/tmp/TemplateEngine
[ERROR] BootClassPathSupported : false
```

just created the folder "mkdir ./target/pit-reports" and it went away. 
this is generating the problem

```
<show>private</show>
```

So we can say you found a bug in maven-javadoc-plugin :)

Comment: Good to know - do I have to report it, or do you already have reported it?

Comment: I just found a work around. You found it you should report it.